# R shiny: how to change the font size (ticks) in the sliderInput?

Tags: shiny, font-size

I would like to reduce the font-size (ticks) in the sliderInput. The UI is too large. Anyone can give helps? Thanks

Simple example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
    min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
  ),
  plotOutput("distPlot")
)


# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs))
  })
}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Best wishes,
hees

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS. Here I am modifying the property of the slider class, so if you have several sliderInput in your code, it will alter all of them.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
    .irs-grid-text {
      font-size: 6px;
    }
    .irs--shiny .irs-min,.irs--shiny .irs-max {
      font-size: 6px;
    }
    .irs--shiny .irs-from,.irs--shiny .irs-to,.irs--shiny .irs-single {
      font-size: 7px;
    }
    "))
  ),
  sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
              min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
  ),
  plotOutput("distPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```